# WPF TextBox and spaces

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, wpf-textbox

I create a string from multiple fields that has leading blanks/spaces suing `StringBuilder`.

When I export it to text file or even insert one by one to WPF `TextBox` and after this copy and paste to Notepad.exe or Notepad++.exe I see the perfect aligned fields and that is ok because of the leading blanks.

But visually in WPF `TextBox` (as well as in WPF `TextBlock` and WPF `RichTextBox`) it gets messing. Take a look at the screemshot below at the top you see `TextBox` and below a Notepad++.

Any clue why does WPF `TextBox` not align characters well?
Can we manage it?

[image]

**XAML**

```
 <TextBox x:Name="TbOutputFile"  IsReadOnly="True"   Foreground="Green" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  TextWrapping="NoWrap" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" />
```

Comment: @StepUp SOrry, I just updated my question with XAML

Comment: you can use monospaced font

Comment: Does it work if you set the font to something that is fixed-width? I think the default font uses different character sizes, which could result in what you are seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a mono space font line Consolas. In most fonts all characters are not the same width. This will cause things to get out of alignment. It a text box it is using a monospace font. Here is a list of sone of them.
[https://www.google.com/search?q=monospace+font+list&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8](https://www.google.com/search?q=monospace%20font%20list&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Or you can use tab characters in a richtext box.